# If I set "variant" oprional, I get "Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type"

Tags: typescript, react-native

In typescript react-native project, this is  component that I set:

```js
    type Variants = "body" | "label" | "caption" | "error" | "hint";
    
    interface TextProps {
      theme?: DefaultTheme;
      // variant?: Omit<keyof Variants, undefined>;
      variant?: Variants;
    }
    
    export const Text = styled.Text<TextProps>`
      ${({ theme }) => defaultTextStyles(theme)}
      // HERE IS THE ISSUE "variants[variant](theme)"
      ${({ variant, theme }) => variants[variant](theme)}
    `;
    
    Text.defaultProps = {
      variant: "body",
    };
```

If I set `variant?: Variants` optional, I get this error from  `${({ variant, theme }) => variants[variant](theme)`. Since "variant" is optional, it can be undefined, so undefined cannot be used as index. But I also set

```js
   Text.defaultProps = {
      variant: "body",
    };
```

default variant should be "body" but this does not kick in. I tried those but did not work

```js
    Text.defaultProps = {
      variant: "body",
    } as Partial<TextProps>;
```

```js
Text.defaultProps = {
  variant: "body",
} as Pick<TextProps, "variant">;
```

Comment: I don't use Styled Component that much but I think you can solve the issue by putting default value like this `${({ variant, theme }) => variants[variant ?? "body"](theme)}`.